# Adding class to hoverable element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, hover

I have a button, which changes its color on hover.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.classList.add('green-background');
```

```css
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: magenta;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green-background {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Click me" />
```

I would like to add it the `green-background` class, so that the button is green in default state and on hover as well.

Comment: So why make it magenta in the first place ? ... simply remove `background: magenta;` from the hover rule

Comment: @LGSon Because before js worked I wanted it to be magenta on hover.

Comment: Then increase specificity for the green background with e.g. `.btn.green-background` and when the class gets added, it stays green

Comment: @LGSon Should this be done within css?

Comment: Yes, e.g. like this (first hover the button, then click it to add the class, hover again) https://jsfiddle.net/15kjd03e/1/

Comment: @LGSon Very nice, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a css rule that specifies the style for .green-background on hover, which you can do by setting styles for `.green-background:hover`

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.classList.add('green-background');
```

```css
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: magenta;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green-background, .green-background:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Click me" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two selectors using `,` the default and the `hover`. See [Groups of selectors on one rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors#Groups_of_selectors_on_one_rule) for more information.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.classList.add('green-background');
```

```css
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: magenta;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green-background:hover,.green-background {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Click me" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function changeclass() {
            const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
            if (!btn.classList.contains('green-background'))
                btn.classList.add('green-background');
            else
                btn.classList.remove('green-background');

        }

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .btn {
      text-decoration: none;
      background: blue;
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .btn:hover {
      background: magenta;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .green-background, .green-background:hover {
      background: green;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Click me" onmouseover="changeclass()" onmouseout="changeclass()" />
```

you asked how to add class by java script :  just add onmouseover="changeclass()" onmouseout="changeclass()" event to button and changeclass function 
but you can also do it by css same as the approved answer.